# String parsing for spanish language detection in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string, parsing, internationalization

I'm in a situation where I'm given a character string and need to determine if the language of the string is Spanish or English. I plan on parsing for stop words - Spanish (`de, es, si, y") vs English ('of', 'is', 'if', 'and')? If there more Spanish occurrences than English occurrences, then, I conclude the page is Spanish.

Are there any Ruby snippets already available to do this? If not, what would be good method for string parsing or regex to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you saw this already? http://www.rubyinside.com/whatlanguage-ruby-language-detection-library-1085.html

Comment: I have 2 questions: is the program allowed to access internet resources, such as, say, Google? And the second, does it need to include parsing and regex? The way I've done it in Python (admittedly, not in Ruby) was I read off of the interface of worldlingo.com, and used their detect_lang javascript function (hence the question of internet access). If you think it may help you, I can post the Python source here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string that contains a sentence (or a series of words, at least), you can use `string.split(' ')` to split the string into an array of words.  From there, you can use `.each` to iterate through the list and process each word.  For example:

```
def detect_language(sentence)
    english_count = 0
    spanish_count = 0
    sentence.split(' ').each {|word|
        if looks_like_english(word)
            english_count += 1
        elsif looks_like_spanish(word)
            spanish_count += 1
        end
    }

    retval = ["spanish", "unknown", "english"]
    retval[(english_count <=> spanish_count) + 1]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the experience with the same task. And decided to refuse of regexp/text-parsing solutions after several days of discussion.

Now i use translation web servers(like google, bing, ...) that supports auto-detect language. I think it's the best method to solve it (if your conditions permit, of course)